# PHP - fopen(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

In my code I create a file called `$cookie`. I than later want to open it and read contents from it, but I get the error `fopen(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.` I have a feeling I messed up something related to paths. Any advice on how to tackle this?

I tried this:

```
<?php
$cookie = 'cookies3.txt';
..
$myfile = fopen("cookies3.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("cookies3.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: `dirname($cookie)` do you really have a directory called `cookies3.txt`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php *"Returns the path of a parent directory."* - Plus, make sure that cookies were first set before attempting to write them. You may have wanted to use `file()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php not `dirname()`.

Comment: yeah that second part is something i found on so and gave it a try. i will delete it.

Comment: check for folder and file permissions then. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Your code works,given what you posted. It's most likely a permissions issue here. If that text file isn't in the same folder as your script, then you need to specify its correct path. Plus make sure the file does exist in the first place.

Comment: `file_get_contents();` don't put yourself in this trouble if it can be that easy, or wait: `file()` even returns an array for each \n isn't that amazingly easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, the file wasn't created. 
All thanks to `fred -ii-.`

Comment: Ah, another happy ending ;-) you're welcome.